# spring batch processor filter listener

Tags: java, spring-batch

How do you catch item which was filtered by returning null in item processor?

I saw there is skip listener but we are not throwing any exception if we need to skip it. We just return null to filter that item out and we want to audit them

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this with `ItemProcessListener.afterProcess`. From the docs:

> Called after ItemProcessor.process(Object) returns. If the processor
>   returns null, this method will still be called, with a null result,
>   allowing for notification of 'filtered' items.

See the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemProcessListener.html#afterProcess-T-S-) for more details.